# How could we identify the tasks that got created as a result of email sync from outlook?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I am required to write a trigger on the tasks created as a result of email sync from Outlook.But the problem is that I am not being able to differentiate between other tasks and the tasks created as a result of Email sync from outlook to salesforce. Is there any field that can let me know that whether the task was created as a result of email sync or other way?

Comment: Is that the tasks moving to unresolved items list just after syncing?

Comment: I really don't have any idea @Santanu,but they're adding up at the Contacts' Open Activities related list

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

By default, there's no distinction. The best solution to differentiate the tasks created from the Outlook to Salesforce sync vs. other tasks is to have a custom field which gets populated during the sync process. This can be a boolean flag or you can store any other sync information which may come in handy at a later stage.

The sync works based on `Subject` and `Due Date`. To find more details on how to control the specific task/ field syncing behavior, read [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_sync_tasks.htm).

Comment: Is it possible to expose custom field only in Inbox ? or Is there any way where we can auto populate the field ?

Answer (score 0):

Task subject will begin with "Email:" if it is created as a result of email sync from
Outlook